# Showing a topological space is not $T_1$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the topological space with $X=(0,1)$ and $T=\{(0,1-\frac{1}{n})|n \in \mathbb{N},n\geq 2\} \cup \{X,Ø\}$, is not $T_1$.
I know that (X,T) is $T_1$ if $\forall x \in X$, $\{x\}$ are closed in (X,T).

Comment: Is the complement of $\{\frac 1 2 \}$ an open set?

Comment: I think it's easier to use definition directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could go about this, depending on what equivalent formulation of $T_1$ you'd like to use: if you're using the fact that a space is $T_1$ if and only if every singleton is closed, you could follow @Kavi Rama Murthy's hint, which very quickly proves the statement; the complement of $\{1/2\}$ in $X$ is the union of the two intervals $(0, 1/2) \cup (1/2, 1)$, which is clearly not in $T$, and is thus not open. Hence, $\{1/2\}$ is not closed, so not every singleton in $X$ is closed i.e. $X$ is not $T_1$.

If you're using the definition that, for any two distinct points $x, y$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $y \not\in U$ and $x \not\in V$, you could also just proceed as follows: choose two arbitrary but distinct points $x, y \in X$ (WLOG assume $x < y$). Then any open set containing $y$ necessarily contains $x$ (any nonempty set in $T$ containing $y$ also contains every element between $0$ and $y$), so $X$ is not $T_1$.